# Plotting Average/Median of each column in data frame grouped by factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make a grouped barplot and I am running into trouble.   For example, if I was using the mtcars dataset and I wanted to group everything by the 'vs' column (col #8), find the average of all remaining columns, and then plot them by group.

Below is a very poor example of what I am trying to do and I know it is incorrect.

Ideally, mpg for vs=1 & vs=0 would be side by side, followed by cyl's means side by side, etc.   I don't care if aggregate is skipped for dyplr or if ggplot is used or even if the aggregate step is not needed...just looking for a way to do this since it is driving me crazy.

```
df = mtcars
agg = aggregate(df[,-8], by=list(df$vs), FUN=mean)
agg
barplot(t(agg), beside=TRUE, col=df$vs))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(vs=factor(vs)) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% 
    gather(Var, Val, -vs) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(x=Var, y=Val, fill=vs))+
    geom_bar(stat='identity', position='dodge')
```

[image]

Or using `base R`

```
 m1 <- as.matrix(agg[-1])
 row.names(m1) <- agg[,1]
 barplot(m1, beside=TRUE, col=c('red', 'blue'), legend=row.names(m1))
```

[image]